# How can I see the thumbnails videos?

Tags: pantheon-files

As you can see in the picture below, only the image shows up its thumbnail, not the video.

How do I see their thumbnails?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you give more information on which version you are using and what system you are running it on?  Video thumbnailing is working for me using elementary 6.0 (not yet released) but not when Files is run on Ubuntu for exampe.

Comment: i using  OS 5.1.2 Hera

Comment: Hmm, the latest released OS version is 5.1.7 - might be worth updating.  Also what do you see in the background context menu for the video folder? Does it have an option "Show thumbnails" or "Hide thumbnails"?   Also, check that you have the package "tumbler-plugins-extra" installed. This package (and the base tumbler package) is missing on Ubuntu which is why thumbnails were not shown.  Installing it fixed it on Ubuntu.  However it should be installed by default on ElementaryOS.